# Importxml functions stopped working on google sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I have a google sheet I use as a stock tracker, and the importxml seemingly randomly stopped working. The line `IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIS?p=DIS", "//*[@id='quote-summary']/div[2]/table/tbody")` for example now returns "Could not fetch url: [https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIS?p=DIS"](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIS?p=DIS%22).

I've tried importxml with a random website `=IMPORTXML("https://www.pinterest.co.uk/geckoboard/","//meta[@property='pinterestapp:followers']/@content")` and it worked fine...

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know how google is getting te content of a url in IMPORTXML(). But if try "wget https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIS?p=DIS" on linux I receive " ERROR 500: Internal Server Error." Not on with "wget https://www.pinterest.co.uk/geckoboard/" Maybe they are making it harder to scrape...?